# GitHub GraphQL. Get list of repositories with one batch request

Tags: github, graphql, github-api

I've got a dynamic list of github repository urls (lets say size is < 100). I'd like to query a particular information of each of them using GraphQL.

Can I do it with one batch request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I've found a solution. Only works if you know global `node_id` of each repository, which is definitely my case.

```
query($ids: [ID!]!) {
   nodes(ids: $ids) {
      ... on Repository {
         name
         description
      }
   }
}
```